# How to use the pipe option of `child_process.spawn`?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I read the Node's documentation, I found this option.

It's easy to understand when setting the `stdin` to `pipe`.
But when you'd like to set the `stderr` or `stdout` to `pipe`?

Can you give me an example when both the `stderr` and `stdout` are set to `pipe`?

```
child_process.spawn(cmd, args, { stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe'] })

// How to use the pipe?
// Usage...
```

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't your code exactly what you want already?

Comment: @jgillich I updated the question. I want to know how to use the pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have looks like it should already be attaching `/dev/null` to stdin, and piping stdin + stdout to respective streams of the parent process. Is that not working?

The same thing can be achieved a few different ways.

Example: pipe stdout + stderr of a `ls -a` to stdout + stderr of the current node process and terminate the node process with the same exit code as the child command

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var ls = spawn("ls -a");
ls.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
ls.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
ls.on("exit", function(code) {
    process.exit(code);
});
```